# Which two are true about the Inventory directory in Oracle 11G?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, open-closed-principle

- A. It is shared by all Oracle software installations on a single server.
- B. It is required only for Oracle Grid Infrastructure and Oracle Database software Installations.
- C. It can be created only if the ORACLE_BASE environment variable is set.
- D. It should be created before installing Oracle software for the first time on a server.
- E. It is owned by the oinstall group, which must be created before installing Oracle software for the first time on a server.

The answer is AD.

I think D is wrong but E is correct.

According to the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/install.112/e47689/pre_install.htm#LADBI1193):

> Oracle Universal Installer creates the directory that you specify and sets the correct owner, group, and permissions for it. You do not have to create it.

So I think D is wrong.

According to the [Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11857_01/install.111/e15838/appdx_creating_os_grps_usrs.htm):

> You must create this group the first time you install Oracle software on the system. The default name chosen for this group is oinstall. This group owns the Oracle inventory that is a catalog of all Oracle software installed on the system.

So I think E is correct.

My question is why D is correct but E is wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Because it is not compulsory  to specify group for oracle inventory

In this window you can also specify the operating system group that has write permissions on the inventory directory. This prevents other users from writing over the Oracle product installation files. Typically the oinstall group is selected.

Comment: According to Oracle doc, The default name chosen for oracle inventory owner is oinstall which must be created the first time you install Oracle software on the system. Oracle Universal Installer creates oracle inventory directory that you specify and sets the correct owner, group, and permission for it. You do not have to create it.